# Tree farming foundation

Tags: terraria-console

If you build and giant wood platform in the sky then add 3 layers of dirt/grass will it grow if I put an acorn

Comment: What do you mean by "3 layers"? 3 tiles deep of dirt? Three separate 1-tile-thick dirt platforms layered above each other? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the only restrictions in regards to your question according to the [Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tree):

> The acorn requires one horizontal space of open ground to either side below it, but at least two unobstructed tiles to the left and right of it.
>
> There must be at least three open tiles between saplings or only one will grow into a tree. This matches the previous rule, i.e. each acorn needs both adjacent tiles free, which means the closest two trees can be is with three tiles between them.

Your method should work, providing you have at least 3 free tiles in between each acorn. The screenshots on the Wiki appear to have just one tile of material.